# Creating Scale application in free plan Openshift

Tags: openshift, openshift-cartridge

**Can i actually create and scale application with my free plan in openshift?**

If yes,
Then when i am running this command

```
rhc app create myApp php-5.4 mysql-5.5 -s
```

After showing `Creating application 'myApp' ...` for a while
**Why**
 does it says

`myemail@gmail.com is currently using 2 out of 3 limit and this application
requires 2 additional gears`

When Actually i haven't crated any application in this account.(full blank)

Comment: Use the contact form at help.openshift.com and we will look into this issue.  Please reference this question in your request.

Comment: Creating application from web was successful later. Yet i have sent a request to `help.openshift.com` regarding this issue. Thanks for response @corey112358